# viewForHeaderInSection is placing header above the tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I overrided the method `viewForHeaderInSection` and I realized by default it adds it on top of the `UItableView`, I would like to send it to the back of the tableView. Any Idea?

Here is my code:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:districtImage];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,300,100);
    NSLog(@"districtImage=%@",districtImage);
    return imageView;
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok I got it to scroll up now:

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = imageView;

my problem now is the header is to big how can I reduce it

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{}

does not seem to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

`-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`

with the same body that should work

Comment: @WarehouseMuzik because the view for HEADER is placed on top of the section but the view for FOOTER is at the end of the section. Wasn't that your question?

Comment: No, I have a footer already, so it does not help, I have it working now but there is a gap between the header and the tableView

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood your question

Comment: fab do you know why there is a gap

Comment: No I'm sorry maybe the image view or the district image have a wrong size?